# How to configure SharePoint 2016 on premise to a public IP?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, alternate-access-mapping

I need a detailed tutorial on how to do alternate access mapping for SharePoint 2016 on premise.

What I have done so far:

- Created a NAT to the server using a Public IP (I can use RDP to reach the server)
- Put the IP address in the Internet section of the AAM of SharePoint.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Did you update the IIS settings? Refer this article http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2010/06/making-a-sharepoint-2010-site-externally-available-alternate-access-mappings-host-header-bindings.html

Comment: Hi @Peter, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: I dont have a domain name, I am using a public ip, in IIS, it doesnt accept the IP as Host Header, How do I achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Before you going to configure alternative access mapping you should be aware of:

- The default zone public URL should be set to a Fully Qualified Domain Name based URL that is appropriate for all users to see. Unless you do this, the names of web servers or their IP addresses might be displayed in parameters that were passed between pages within SharePoint.
- Host-named site collections can’t use alternate access mappings. Host-named site collections are automatically considered in the Default zone, and the URL of the request must not be changed between the user and the server.
- Alternate access mappings allow you to expose a web application in as many as five different zones, with a different IIS website backing each zone, some people mistakenly refer to this as having up to five different web applications sharing the same content databases. In reality, there is just one web application.
- You can’t delete the last internal URL for the default zone.

**To configure AAM do the following:**

- Configure alternate access mapping via Central Administration.
- Configure SharePoint Site IIS Bindings.
- Configure Hosts file
- Disable loop Back Check
- Add “A” record on DNS server for your URL to point to Server IP or Load balancer IP based on your topology

Check the detail steps at [CONFIGURING ALTERNATE ACCESS MAPPING INSIDE SHAREPOINT SERVER](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/26/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Comment: I dont have a domain name, I am using a public ip, in IIS, it doesnt accept the IP as Host Header, How do I achieve this

Comment: follow the same steps at https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/26/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/ and change the domain name to IP in the mentioned steps it's the same!